# hibernate interceptor to trace an object and update thirdparty cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, architecture, system

I have a set of  applications (running on different JVMs) in which an entity Student is saved into the database (shared database). I want to create a dashboard system, which will update the webpage almost real time on how many Students have been saved (registered into the system). So instead of finding the place where the students are saved in a big code base, I thought I would introduce interceptor or listeners (since all the application uses hibernate). I will introduce a caching layer which will update the cache representing the students information, and instead of hitting the database (my db is already overloaded) I could use the cache layer to get the information about the students enrolled.

The dashboard would look like below.
Total students : 120.

Recent registration:

UserA [TimeStamp]

UserB [TimeStamp]

...
..

I would need the following to ensure my system works fine.

1. I need to be sure the user is committed to database. am not sure if
   onSave() method guarantees committing to the database.
2. afterTransactionCompletion does sound like it called after the
   transaction committed/rolled-back, but does not give me the entity
   object , which I would use to update the cache.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is which of the onSave() or the afterTrasactionCompletion fits my job ? Or is there any better approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So instead of finding the place where the students are saved in a big
>   code base, I thought I would introduce interceptor or listeners (since
>   all the application uses hibernate).

I think is quite strange. In whatever big code base you have, there should be only one place where students are saved into DB: `StudentRepository`. This repository can be injected with your `UnitOfWork` instance and that `UnitOfWork` should have `addAfterTransactionHandler()` method. And that solves your problem, I believe.

Comment: Well, My big code base ( essentially different systems , thus jvms ) follows different coding practices ( not necessarily domain driven design ). And strange ? Yes, they are old code , and I don't want to touch them. 
Also addAfterTransactionCommit() ( I think you meant that ) has Transaction passed to it . not the entity which I could use.  How do i get that ? Being interceptor this will be called by many other commits.

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper I see. Well, you are in a difficult position then ;) BTW, I am not sure a Repository pattern belongs to DDD only. It is utilized commonly to employ [ISP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle) (separate database queries from the rest of the code).